# I don't have "Mask Slice to New Object" button in Sculpt Mode

Tags: masking, sculpt-mode

I want to separate masked mesh part, I googled that there is suppose to be a button for this, but I don't have it. I'm using Blender 2.81.

I tried to do "Mask Extract", but it works weird, it just makes a pool of polygons. I don't want to separate it via Edit Mode, because it is too much polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just because 2.81 don't have it. In version 3.4, this button is definitely there.

Comment: thanks, stranger

Comment: I always wonder what's the logic behind choosing to use old versions? I understand not switching versions in the middle of one project, but 2.81?.. Why?

Comment: I just haven't updated it, I didn't realize it's super old